# Trouble running Word 2007 for legacy software with a Microsoft Office 365 installation

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, office365

I have Microsoft Office 2007 installed on my work desktop. It's essential that I keep Microsoft Word 2007 as my primary word processor, as I have legacy corporate software that interfaces with it.

I installed Office 365 and this reset my default Word to Word 365. This broke the legacy software I had, even when I specified for Word files to be opened with Word 2007 only. I ended up having to roll back the entire install to get things fixed.

I would really like to use Office 365 for my daily tasks and still have Word 2007 work with my legacy software. Do you have any idea how I might have them both installed and coexisting peacefully? Apparently I can't just choose not to install Word 365.

Answer (score 0):

Direct from Microsoft:

> Office 365 is not designed to work with Office 2007 because Office
>   2007 left mainstream support on October 12, 2012. Office 365 does not
>   offer code fixes to resolve problems you encounter when using the
>   service with Office 2007. You should expect the quality of the user
>   experience to diminish over time, and many new Office 365 experiences
>   will not work at all. We recommend that you upgrade as soon as
>   possible to Office 365 ProPlus or Office Professional Plus 2013 for
>   the best experience with Office 365.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Office-365-system-requirements-719254c0-2671-4648-9c84-c6a3d4f3be45)

Answer (score 0):

When you logon to your Office 365 portal, back under Software (same place you get Office), look under the tools options and download and run the desktop assistant. Make sure your Office 2007 is running all it's updates.

Though it may no longer be officially supported - most function should still work.  Office 2007 worked with SharePoint 2013, and Outlook is a mail client so at the very least if native connections are not working for you - you can fallback to IMAP mail (Or just use Outlook Web App). What you won't get are native Save to location in Word clients, or direct integration with things like Office Add-ins (app).

With Office, there are always some issues when running different versions side by side.  If you want to install the newer versions of office alongside 2007, you can do so, but you need to run a repair on your 2007 Office AFTER you have installed the 2013 versions.